# How to append characters to selected text in textbox/textarea in JavaScript on key press

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have textbox/textarea input fields by selecting some text inside e.g.

> Test Message with sub text and last message

on selecting "Mes" and press <kbd>ctrl+B</kbd> it should append `<b>` (or any character or multiple chars of my choice)  to selected text at both ends in JavaScript as shown below

> Test `<b>Mes<b>`sage with sub text and last message

I am able to simulate <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd> key event successfully but not able to replace selected text with new text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get selection start and end from corresponding fields in textarea.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<textarea>Test Message with sub text and last message</textarea>
<script>
jQuery('textarea').on('keydown', function(e) {
 if (e.keyCode == 66 && (e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey)) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var text = jQuery(this).val();
  var start = this.selectionStart;
  var end = this.selectionEnd;
  var selection = '<b>' + text.substring(start, end) + '</b>';
  text = text.substring(0, start) + selection + text.substring(end);
  jQuery(this).val(text);
  this.selectionStart = start;
  this.selectionEnd = start + selection.length;
 }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for quick response

Answer (score 1):

Following function wraps the selected text in a text area with given string .

I have written an example case

```
function wrapSelection(textArea, wrappingString) {
    var s = textArea.selectionStart;
    var e = textArea.selectionEnd;
    var oldValue = textArea.value;
    var newValue = oldValue.slice(0, s) + wrappingString + oldValue.slice(s, e) + wrappingString + oldValue.slice(e, oldValue.length);
    textArea.value = newValue;
}

var element = document.getElementById('your-input-element');
element.onselect = function () {
    wrapSelection(element, '<b>');
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for quick response